# Как определить текущий язык (не локаль!) Windows 7?

Tags: c++

Интересует  метод определения локализации Windows 7 на с++(не [локали](http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7), а именно языка интерфейса), например "Пуск" в русской версии, "Start" -  в английской.

Подозреваю, что эти строки где-то хранятся, вот только где и как их извлечь?

Comment: попробуйте функцию LANGID GetSystemDefaultLangID(void); из winapi

Comment: @Оля Зайцева, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вот получилось

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int   ret;

    ret = GetSystemDefaultLangID();

    if (ret == 1049)
        cout << "is type os russian interface" << endl;
    else
        cout << "is type os not russian interface" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

В настройках проекта не забудьте включить Использовать MFC в общей DLL, чтоб ошибок не было.

Comment: Думаю, что 

     cout << setlocale(LC_ALL, "") << '\n';

тоже выведет нужную информацию  
(и заодно установит default локализацию).

Comment: @avp я так понял, не язык нужен, а русифицирована ли сама винда.

Comment: @perfect, 

    char *t;
    cout << (t = setlocale(LC_ALL, "")) << '\n';
    cout << (strncmp(t, "Rus", 3) ? "not rus" : "Rus!!!") << '\n';

или каким-нибудь другим способом.

Comment: @avp винда также может также быть с французким переводом и тд. я так понял моя функция коды языков интерфейса возращает

Comment: @perfect, в вопросе автора явно указано, что требуется узнать ***НЕ*** локаль. Ваша же [функция](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319073(v=vs.85).aspx) возвращает именно локаль и если изменить ее в региональных настройках, то выводимое значение будет совершенно другое, хотя  язык интерфейса остается прежним. Тут скорее нужна [GetSystemDefaultUILanguage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318123(v=vs.85).aspx) и [MUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319073(v=vs.85).aspx) который я описал ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Текущий язык интерфейса: `HKEY\_LOCAL\_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MUI\UILanguages`

Языковые пакеты находятся в самой папке windows и обычно имеют имя самого пакета, к примеру: `en\_EN, fr\_FR, ru\_RU`. В этих папках содержатся бинарные файлы с расширением .mui (Multilingual User Interface File), которые, по идее, как раз содержат строки локализации интерфейса windows. Правда, можно ли их использовать и как, не знаю.

***UPD 1***

По примеру [[@perfect](/users/2872/perfect)](/users/2872/perfect) нашел, что данную опцию выбора пакета языка так же выводит [GetSystemDefaultUILanguage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318123(v=vs.85).aspx). Информацию по использованию Multilingual User Interface File можно начать искать [отсюда](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319073(v=vs.85).aspx).